# UA-Platform-Version header not working for webpages

Tags: php, https, http-headers

I get the following code added between `<head>` and `</head>` to detect Windows 11:

```
<meta http-equiv="Accept-CH" content="Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version">
```

But I couldn't find this Accept-CH on my webpage. It should signify the platform version (like "14.0.0") . Now it only shows for the other files like js, css and image.

How can I get this header working?

Answer (score 0):

That's a HTML header.

You should set it to in a HTTP header on server side (PHP).

```php
header('accept-ch', 'Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version');
```

then, your browser will send it.